# How to select string between delimiters and insert into other column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, substring, delimiter

Let's say I have a table in a MySQL database with two columns `first_string` and `second_string`.

`first_string` contains this sentence: `Hello! This is my first test. I like this test.`

I want to get all between the delimiters `my` and `test` (including the delimiters itself) and insert it in `second_string`.

So `second_string` should be: `my first test`.

It's important to take the first available delimiters: I need `my first test` and **not** `my first test. I like this test`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('my', @Text), CHARINDEX('test',@text) - CHARINDEX('my', @Text) + Len('test'));
```

But I don't know how to do the rest. And will that code always look for the first available delimiter?

I hope anybody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just store the "first" and "second" variables and create the first and second strings dynamically? It would save database storage space and be easier to implement.

Comment: The problem is, `first_string` is already stored like this. I need to extract the content for `second_string`. When finished I'll delete the whole `first_string` column.

Comment: @forrestmid Do you understand what I mean? Do you know a solution?

Comment: @forrestmid It needn't to be optimized. I just have to edit some hundred rows like that once.

Comment: @forrestmid This is an MySQL/SQL question, no PHP. Sorry for that, I removed the `PHP` tag.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, deleted those comments.

Comment: @forrestmid How can I test your code? I'll have do display the result in some way. How can I do that?

Comment: What does the current query give you as a result?

Comment: Oh, it's php code what you provided, but I need SQL code.

Comment: Is the format always exactly like how you have it set, minus the "first" and "like" bits? We could split the string with the period and accomplish what you're looking for, just reading through the commons on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean some thing like this ?

mysql> SET @Text='Hello! This is my first test. I like this test.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

```
SET @Text='Hello! This is my first test. I like this test.';

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@Text, INSTR(@Text,'my')
    , (INSTR(@Text,'test') - INSTR(@Text,'my') + CHAR_LENGTH('test')))
    INTO @result;

SELECT @result;
```

**Sample**

```
    mysql> SET @Text='Hello! This is my first test. I like this test.';
    mysql> SELECT
        ->     SUBSTRING(@Text, INSTR(@Text,'my')
        ->     , (INSTR(@Text,'test') - INSTR(@Text,'my') + CHAR_LENGTH('test')))
        ->     INTO @result;
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT @result;
    +---------------+
    | @result       |
    +---------------+
    | my first test |
    +---------------+
    1 row in set (0,00 sec)

    mysql>
```

Comment: `char_length` is a better approach than mine. You got my vote, here's a SQL fiddle that you can modify to show this approach. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d94899/1

Comment: Yes, but It seems not to work if there's already the ending delimiter before the starting delimiter. Means: If I have `Test: Hello! This is my first test. I like this test.` I get no result instead of `my first test`.

Comment: @user7128548 So in the math operation you're going to need to make `INSTR(@Text,'test')` execute on the first found bit rather than the whole string..

Comment: @chris85 Yes, that's it.